# Who was the Christian missionary who helped reform English Missions?

Tags: missions, missionary

I recall reading a biography of a Christian missionary who(after some difficulty, to be sure) arrived in the country he was preparing to serve. Upon arrival, however, he was appalled by the missionaries already there. they lived in a fenced and gated community and basically played the days away, remaining quite English and even owning slaves, I think I recall. The missionary in question rebuked them and left their gated community. He was one of the first missionaries to dress like the people and preach in their language. He lived like them and was a good missionary.

Who was this reforming missionary? 
I do not know the exact country, but I'm fairly sure a sea-bordering country in Asia, such as Burma, or Thailand, etc.

Comment: Do you happen to at least know the country?

Comment: These tags might need some work.

Comment: Hudson Taylor fits some elements of this.

Comment: William Carey? I bet. India (Eastern) late 1700s

Comment: ah, yes, the name rings a bell. I will check this out. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hudson Taylor for sure.

Have a read of this very short biography in Christianity Today

http://www.christianitytoday.com/ch/131christians/missionaries/htaylor.html